# Timestamp function changing, how to fix this problem?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, custom-function

I have a problem while using script editors to creat timestamp for time out record.

Here is the function I have collected on one topic in stack when searching for a solution:

[image]

The problem is if I change the rows by moving, the timestamp will be automatically recorded to the new one. And this will be wrongly recorded in the Google sheet.

The example is here:

[image]

[image]

How could I stop the changing when using the function created by Script?

Comment: Why are you using a custom function when you can simply insert the date/time and format the cell? By using a custom function, the value will change whenever it's recalculated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Here code should be included as text not as image. Also you should include a brief description of your search /research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Out()` as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) means that it will be recalculated as per your spreadsheet [settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515). I believe this defaults to "on change", which is why it updates when you move the row.

As `Out()` is only use to provide a formatted date/time stamp, I recommend that you instead use a [keyboard shortcut](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110) to enter the date/time and set the correct [formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470) in that column.

To insert the date and time, you can use (PC) `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ;` or (Mac) `⌘ + Option + Shift + ;`.

Comment: Hi Diego, I have also used  Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ; but sometimes it is not worked. Could you have any ideas to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: @HaiAnhNguyen No, I'm sorry, but I don't know why that would happen.